# Multiple users EDB Postgres Enterprise Manager

Tags: postgresql, pem, edb

It is posible to configure pem to access different users, back they had their own space?
I mean if I login as user 1 and add some server, then my collegue login with user 2 and see what I add. And if the user 2 add the same servers, pem show them duplicate.

And we don't want that. We want that every user had their own profile.

Thank you